# ATL COM Executable Server: connection Points

Tags: c++, dll, com, 32bit-64bit, atl

I have the following VC++ solution that work perfectly (This is a simplified example) that contains 3 projects:

1. BasicFunctionDLL, 32 Bits DLL that contains two functions:

   `void DLLDIR __stdcall SetMathOPFunction(MathOPFunction cmpFunc);` this function set up callback function.

   `int DLLDIR __stdcall MathematicalOperations(int Value1, int Value2);` this function call Callback when called.
2. Server: 32 Bits ATL COM DLL server, this server is playing the role
   of wrapper to the dll “BasicFunctionDLL” and a bridge so that the
   DLL can access one of the client function.
3. Client: 32 bits MFC application, and a Basic ATL COM DLL Server
   client with Sink Class.

This is the link to the project on Github : https://github.com/AnnabiGihed/Solution2

All those three-project work perfectly, I can set the Callback of the DLL “BasicFunctionDLL” thanks to the ATL COM Server, and the “BasicFunctionDLL” DLL can call the function provided by the client as a function pointer.

However, I have to migrate the Client to 64 bits, and keep both Server and BasicFunction in 32 bits.

When I did that, the Client became unable to call the Server.

So, my questions are:

1. What should I do so that the client can communicate with Server without changing the architecture of both of the “Server” and “BasicFunctionDLL”?
2. After doing some research, I found out that I should change the
   Server from (ATL COM Dll Server) to (ATL COM Executable Server). Is
   this the only possible solution?
3. if the answer to Question 2 is yes, can someone provide me with a
   good example for how to achieve the same that has been achieved in
   the provided server example (Talking about setting up a DLL CallBack
   and Calling one of the client function)? because it seems like the
   connection point work in different way in ATL COM Executable Server.

Comment: without coding anything, you can try to host your COM DLL in COM "Component Services". Create a COM+ application, put your component in it, and configure it's activated as a "server application" - this is not the default config - it will run in an out-of-process surrogate. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681278.aspx

Comment: I don’t think that this is the most practical solution.
I already have an ATL COM project that wrap the DLL and what you are suggesting is adding a wrapper to the ATL COM project itself. That would be confusing and risky.
And don’t you think that, the connection point should be redone so that the client could communicate with COM+ application?

Comment: COM supports a surrogate, a 32-bit host process for the legacy in-process server.  No real difference from the out-of-process server, except that you don't have to change the code at all.  dllhost.exe is the default surrogate.  Requires registry hokey-pokey so the 64-bit app can still see the server and COM knows to activate the host.  And registered proxy/stub for both bitnesses so the calls can be marshaled.  No special consideration for the connection point since it uses IDispatch.  But if you don't think that COM+ is practical then you'll dismiss this as well.  So fix the code.

Comment: Component Services does not "wrap", it's a COM surrogate. It's a Windows component that's there for about 20 years that allows you (among many other things) to transform an in-process COM server into an out-of-process COM server in about 5 minutes. I don't see the risk, if it doesn't work you can remove the component and delete the COM app.